# Kubernetes HorizontalPodAutoscaler maxReplicas

Tags: kubernetes

I have doubts about the use of HorizontalPodAutoscaler (HPA) in Kubernetes, what are the best practices of using HPA, especially in the implementation of MaxReplicate, as an example, If I have a cluster with 3 workers nodes running a single app, and setting up the HPA to scale up to 20 pods, but it is a good practice scale pods 3x more than the available nodes? Or scale the pods up to the same quantity of available worker nodes in the cluster as a better approach?

Comment: having one or two Pods per node would indeed make more sense, although you should make sure that when doing so, your Pods can leverage all that CPU (mono-threaded apps might work better with multiple single-CPU Pods). all in all, you should experiment to find a suitable combination of resource limits/requests, initial replicas, max replicas, which metric should drive scale in/out, ...

Comment: guessing you are aiming to autoscaling, I strongly suggest to use prometheus adapter and grafana so you can execute top pods to see resource/s usage. Then you will be able to define a suitable scale up/down logic on demand :)

Answer (score 2):

first of all you need to test your application and decide a reasonable resources per pod "request and limits"

After setting the limit per pod then you know how many pods your cluster can maintain.
`for example if you have total/free 10 cpu and 10 Gi memory over the cluster  and you set limit per pod to have 1 cpu and 1 Gi memo then you can run up to 10 pods.`

then it's time to run your load test and fire the expected traffic at its max with the lowest number of pods you're planning to run that fit the normal/daily traffic .. gradually startup new pod and check if you can handle the high traffic or you need to add more pods still .. repeat this till you reach a appropriate number of pods. then you got the maximum number of pods that you can configure in your HPA.